# Is there a way to grab the x and y position of an element on a page without it being absolute using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to grab the x and y position of an element if it's not positioned absolute using jquery?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) method should do this.

It returns an **object** which has `left` and `top` attributes.

```
var offset = $('foo').offset();
var offsetLeft = offset.left;
var offsetTop = offset.top;
```

Comment: Coming soon: `let { offetLeft, offsetTop } = $( 'foo' ).offset();`